# C: functions won't run in a loop and read from a file

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that will convert a number into its prime factorization. For example, 2048=2^11 the program will output 211 (since this value will be used in a different function.). The program then prints the prime factorization and the number in a  file. The issue I'm having is having the two functions, digitCount and FdigitCount, run in a loop and read the values from the file and then compare the amount of digits in the prime factorization to the number of digits in the normal number, then if it is less, printing the numbers out.

```
int digitCount(int n){
    int digits = 0;
    while(n!=0) {
        n/=10;             //divides the number by 10 and adds one to the digits   until it is no longer divisible by 10.
        ++digits;
    }
    return digits;
}

int fdigitCount(int p){ //this function is used the count the digits of the prime factorization.
    int fdigits = 0;
    while(p!=0) {
        p/=10;             //divides the number by 10 and adds one to the fdigits until it is no longer divisible by 10.
        ++fdigits;
    }
    return fdigits;
}


int main(void) {
    FILE* primes = NULL; //file pointer to the file that will contain all the prime factors of a number
    int num;
    int count;
    int digits;
    int limit;
    int i;
    int j=2;
    int fdigits;
    int frugalNum;
    int normNum;

    primes = fopen("primes.txt", "w+");
    if (primes == NULL){
        printf("Could not open primes.txt");
    }

    printf("Enter a limit: ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    for (i=2; i <= limit; i++){
        num = i;
        j = i;
        count = 0;
        if (num%2 == 0){
            while (num%2 == 0)
            {
                num = num/2;
                count++;
            }
            if (count > 1){
                fprintf(primes, "2%d", count);
            }
            else {
                fprintf(primes, "2");
            }
        }
        else if(num%2 != 0) {
            for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(num); i = i+2)
            {
                // While i divides n, print i and divide n
                count = 0;
                while (num%i == 0)
                {
                    num = num/i;
                    count++;
                }
                if (count > 1){
                    fprintf(primes, "%d%d", i, count);
                }
                else if (count==1){
                    fprintf(primes, "%d", i);
                }
            }

        }
        if (num > 2){
            fprintf (primes, "%d", num);
        }
        fprintf(primes, " %d", j);
        fprintf(primes, "\n");
    }
    while (!feof(primes)){
        fscanf(primes, "%d %d", &frugalNum, &normNum);
        if (fdigitCount(frugalNum) < digitCount(normNum)){
            printf("%d\n", normNum);
        }
    }
    fclose(primes);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did I miss an fclose(...) and an fopen(...) or you're trying to read from a file still opened in "append" mode?

Comment: @MarcoSanfilippo, looks like he opened in `w+` (read/write) mode.

Comment: Your two functions are the same. Only names differs, which has no effect outside the function. So you can replace `fdigitCount(frugalNum) < digitCount(normNum)` by `digitCount(frugalNum) < digitCount(normNum)`, and suppress `fdigitCount` function.

Comment: @Chad, I guess you're right! :) btw, doesn't the file pointer still point to the end of the file after the last printf()?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't read the file by looping until `feof()` returns `true`. It returns `true` after you've passed the EOF, and so the last values you read will be garbage. Change your loop to:

```
while (fscanf(primes, "%d %d", &frugalNum, &normNum) == 2) {
    /* Do stuff with frugalNum and normNum */
}
```

Additionally, I couldn't help noticing that `digitCount()` and `fdigitCount()` do exactly the same thing. Why do you need both of them?

Comment: Thanks, I thought i needed both of them since I was comparing the output of each. I realize now that I don't need fdigitCount. What does the ==2 in the while statement mean?